# Loading cookies in python

Tags: python, cookies

I am a novice programmer attempting to access google insights using python.  I can access sites which dont require cookies fine, but i cant seem to properly pass the cookies along.  The cookines file was exported from mozilla firefox, is in the Z: drive which is also where im running python from.

Im also pretty sure my code for saving the file could be better done than reading and writing but I dont know how to do that either.  Any helpo would be appreciated.

```
import urllib2
import cookielib
import os

url = "http://www.google.com/insights/search/overviewReport?q=eagles%2Ccsco&geo=US&cmpt=q&content=1&export=2"
cj = cookielib.MozillaCookieJar()
cj.load('cookies6.txt')
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
file = opener.open(url)
output = open('test2.csv','wb')
output.write(file.read())
output.close()
```

Comment: Have a look at [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/), it does handle cookies well (IIRC).

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested your code however:

As far as I can tell there seems to be nothing wrong with your code

I've tried the url you're searching and had no problems downloading the csv **without** any cookies

In my previous experience with google, you might be looking at the problem the wrong way, it is not that you don't have the right cookies but that google automatically blocks requests from bots. **If this is the case** you must replace the user agent http header to mimic an actual browser. Beware however that this is against googles terms of service **and** if you make too many requests per minute google will block all requests from your ip for about 8h.